# 1-dimensional representations and anti-automorphisms.

Tags: representation-theory

Suppose we are in the following setting. Let $A$ be an associative algebra and over a field $\mathbf{K}$, $B\subset A$ a subalgebra and $M$ be a finite dimensional left module of $A$. Let us furthermore suppose that each finite dimensional left or right module $N$ of $A$ is completely reducible into irreducible modules when restricted to $B$. Suppose that we are given a involution anti-autormophism of $\Theta:A\to A$, which not necessarily fixes $B$.

My question is as follows: Suppose $M$ can be written as $M=\oplus M_i$ multiplicity free as a $B$ module, where $M_1$ a $1-$dimensional module. Via the anti-automorphism $\Theta$, $M$ can also be decomposed as a right module $M=\bigoplus N_i$ again $M$ contains $M_1$ as a irreducible right module as it is 1-dimensional. My question is if the embeddings $M_1\hookrightarrow M$ and $M_1\hookrightarrow M$ as left and right modules of $B$ coincide.

Comment: I don't understand why $M$, as a right module, contains the same one-dimensional $B$-representation. For instance, take $A=B$ to be the group algebra of $S_3$ over $\mathbf{C}$ and $\Theta$ to be the anti-automorphism sending $w$ to $\mathrm{sign}(w) w^{-1}$ for each $w \in S_3$. Then if $M$ is the trivial one-dimensional $A$-module, twisting by $\Theta$ produces the sign representation.